# jquery - take a set of hrefs from a list and apply those hrefs to another list in order

Tags: jquery, loops, each

So for example, I have a list and I need to extract the hrefs from it:

```
<ul class="list1">
<li><a href="link1">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="link2">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="link3">Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

BTW, this forums spam protection is not letting me put any more hyper links which is why the code above is semantically incorrect.

And apply those hrefs to the list below in order

```
<ul class="list2">
<li><a>Link1</a></li>
<li><a>Link2</a></li>
<li><a>Link3</a></li>
</ul>
```

It is to be dynamic (meaning as many hrefs in the first list as I want), so I'm not looking to use eq or nth, I've gotten this far by reading help in this forum, but am unclear on how to continue with applying the hrefs to the second list:

```
var hrefs = '';

$('ul#direction-fade-slider li a.url').each(function(idx, item) {  
  hrefs += item.href + '\n';  
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: is the 2nd list already built? you just want the href injected inside the a, or do you want the li and a tags generated?

Comment: nope, they are already generated using a plugin, I was just looking to "inject" existing hrefs in order, thanks for editing the above code, your example below makes sense, I'll try it out and report back. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop like this:

```
var anchors = $("ul.list2 a");
$("ul.list1 a").each(function(i) {
   anchors.get(i).href = this.href;
});
```

All this is doing it getting the destination anchors (or you can reverse it...), looping through the `<a>` elements in order and setting the `href` on the corresponding one at the same index in the destination `.list2`.

Alternatively, you could use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
var source = $("ul.list1 a");
$("ul.list2 a").attr('href', function(i) {
   return source.eq(i).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: Wow, I incredibly over thought this entire approach. I have literally searched and tried everything and I can't believe it was this simple. Nick, much appreciated for the advice. I'm liking the fact that this forum is thoroughly indexed by Google so that others can make use of these approaches. 

BTW, I used your second approach and it did exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks again!